# jQuery.each and setTimeout don't play together well (possibly)?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

So, I read a lot about the issue. Nothing I was able to find online resolved my problem. Here is a bit of code:

```
jQuery( 'input:not([type=submit]):not([type=hidden]), textarea' ).on( 'click', function() {

    $this = jQuery( this );
    parentWrap = $this.parents( 'label' );
    inputLabel = parentWrap.find( '.label' );
    otherInput = jQuery( 'input:not([type=submit]):not([type=hidden]), textarea' ).not( this );

    if ( ! parentWrap.is( '.focused' ) ) {
        parentWrap.addClass( 'focused' );
        setTimeout( function() {
            inputLabel.addClass( 'focused' );
        }, 1000 );
    }

    otherInput.each( function( index, elem ) {
        elem = jQuery( elem );
        elemVal = elem.val();
        elemParentWrap = elem.parents( 'label' );
        elemInputLabel = elemParentWrap.find( '.label' );
        if ( elemParentWrap.is( '.focused' ) ) {
            if ( 0 === jQuery.trim( elemVal ).length ) {
                elemParentWrap.removeClass( 'focused' );
                setTimeout( function() {
                    elemInputLabel.removeClass( 'focused' );
                }, 1000 );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The process:

1. I click the input, two elements related to that input have `.focused` classes added. One of those classes is added with delay.
2. Second part of the function goes through every input on page, except
   of the clicked one, checking, if its elements got class `.focused`. When no class found it doesn't execute anything.
3. I click another input on the same page, it goes through point 1. everything works ok. Every two elements (`label` and `.label`) related to any other input (other than the one clicked) are supposed to have their class `.focused` removed, (one of those related elements to have class removed with delay), but removing with delay doesn't happen.

How to sort it out?

PS, hope I put everything clear. If not please ask a question. There is also small input value check in the code. Please ignore it as it's not relevant for the question.

PS2, when I remove timeout from second function both elements related to the input have their classes removed.

Comment: Show some rendered markup perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not declare your variables, and so they are global. For instance, take `elemInputLabel`. The `each` loop will set that variable to its last value, and then 1 second later all the timers trigger their callbacks, which *all* reference the same variable, which has the same value.

The solution is to use `var` like `var elemInputLabel =`. Now you have separate variables for each callback of the `each` method. Make sure to declare all your variables so they are local to their functions.

Comment: What I was just about to post regarding this also.

Comment: Ok, seriously it was that easy? changing variable scope from global to local? And yes it works!!